# Flink cep MATCH_RECOGNIZE not processing all events

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-cep

I am using MATCH_RECOGNIZE for pattern matching in events, I am trying to find average usage less than 60 withing 10 seconds interval, the issue here is that in result i am only seeing only 2 result (till the marked position in the data bellow) not sure why further data is not processed or there is some problem with my query.

```
CREATE TABLE CPU_IN_TIMEBASED (
    hostname STRING,
    cpu STRING,
    usage DOUBLE,
    occurred_at BIGINT,
    time_ltz AS TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(occurred_at, 3),
    WATERMARK FOR time_ltz AS time_ltz - INTERVAL '5' SECONDS
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
  'topic' = 'cpu_load_timebased',
  'value.format' = 'json',
  'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset'
);

SELECT * FROM CPU_IN_TIMEBASED
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    PARTITION BY hostname
    ORDER BY time_ltz
    MEASURES
        FIRST(A.time_ltz) as start_tstamp,
        LAST(A.time_ltz) as end_tstamp,
        AVG(A.usage) as avgUsage,
        A.cpu as brain,
        A.occurred_at as ts
        AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
    PATTERN (A+ B) WITHIN INTERVAL '5' SECOND
    DEFINE
        A AS AVG(A.usage) < 60
) MR;
```

```
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":95,"occurred_at":1691645762224} x
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":35,"occurred_at":1691645764078} -
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":63,"occurred_at":1691645765122}  |
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":24,"occurred_at":1691645766158}  | 1st match
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":86,"occurred_at":1691645767188}  |
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":82,"occurred_at":1691645768286} -
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":73,"occurred_at":1691645769315} x
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":23,"occurred_at":1691645770335} -  skipped?
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":37,"occurred_at":1691645771365} -  2nd match 
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":84,"occurred_at":1691645772383}    result till 2nd match
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":39,"occurred_at":1691645773408}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":18,"occurred_at":1691645774428}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":77,"occurred_at":1691645775459}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":91,"occurred_at":1691645776478}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":35,"occurred_at":1691645777498}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":28,"occurred_at":1691645778532}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":41,"occurred_at":1691645779674}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":50,"occurred_at":1691645780703}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":81,"occurred_at":1691645781723}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":20,"occurred_at":1691645782755}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":35,"occurred_at":1691645783774}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":43,"occurred_at":1691645784794}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":22,"occurred_at":1691645785812}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":37,"occurred_at":1691645786831}
{"hostname":"one","cpu":"cpu1","usage":64,"occurred_at":1691645787861}
```

Result SS: [Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOwfq.png)

I am not sure how does it works but not able to trace it